# LDAP filter: Can I search for the department number of a client in a multi-valued attribute?

Tags: filter, ldap, ldap-query

Can I retrieve the department number of a customer out of a multi value attribute? Lets assume that I have a user which can get access to several customers and all the customers have other department structures. 
So, I want to store these information in a multi value field with the following structure: customer:departmentNumber

Now the example: I would like to retrieve the department number **124** from customer **400**, how is this possible? Example of user below:

```
dn: cn=joe,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com
cn: joe
department number: 300: 1; 400: 124; 108: 25;
```

I just want to retrieve the **124**, nothing else.
Is it something like this? departmentNumber=400:*;

Comment: No ideas? Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

In the structure shown, you have no method to identify "customer 400".

BTW: "department number" would not be a valid LDAP attribute name.

Not sure what format the structure is in either.

In LDIF format the structure would be more like:

```
dn: cn=joe,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com
cn: joe
departmentnumber: 300
departmentnumber: 1
departmentnumber: 400
departmentnumber: 124
departmentnumber: 108
departmentnumber: 25
customer: 400
```

In which case the filter would be:

```
(&(customer=400)(departmentnumber=400))
```

If you were using ldapsearch it would look something like:

ldapsearch -D "cn=Administrator" -w secret -p 389 -h dc.company.com -b "ou=people,dc=company,dc=com" -s sub "(&(customer=400)(departmentnumber=400))"

This would return all entries that match the filter "(&(customer=400)(departmentnumber=400))".

If you receive a searchResult, you can be assured that the departmentnumber=400.

You might get more than one result.

-jim

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve just

```
departmentnumber: 400: 124
```

if the user entries contain more than on value for the attribute  ***departmentnumber***. LDAP will return all of the values for deparmentnumber for that user entry and you will need to exclude the ones you don't want on the client side.

The best you can do from a retrieval perspective is this...

```
dn: cn=joe,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com
departmentnumber: 300: 1
departmentnumber: 400: 124; 
departmentnumber: 108: 25;
```

if departmentnumber is multi-valued too you cannot guarantee the sort order.